# Aws pinpoint : Send sms from aws sub account

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-pinpoint

We are using pinpoint to send sms from our Spring boot server hosted in aws (Main account). We have 1 sub account where we have configured pinpoint. 
We have setup the main account to send sms from account id of sub account (pipoint application id).
We are using application id of pinpoint and long code that we have . Just this two things to connect to app.
we are getting this error in our spring boot application.
Resource not found (Service: AmazonPinpoint; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException)

Thanks for the help.